# lucene.net performance issue with custom LetterTokenizer

Tags: lucene

I'm using lucene.net 3.0.3 and I have a simple customized analyzer and tokenizer which are breaking the terms by TAB. I measured it and this turns out that the indexing is twice as slow as using a StandardAnalyzer (which does many more things). Do you know what the problem might be, or if there is a better solution ?

Code is below

```cs
public class CustomAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        return new CustomTokenizer(reader);
        //return new LetterTokenizer(reader);
    }

    public override TokenStream ReusableTokenStream(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = this.PreviousTokenStream as Tokenizer;
        if (tokenizer == null)
        {
            tokenizer = new CustomTokenizer(reader);
            //tokenizer = new LetterTokenizer(reader);
        }
        else
        {
            tokenizer.Reset(reader);
        }

        return tokenizer;
    }
}

public class CustomTokenizer : LetterTokenizer
{
    public CustomTokenizer(TextReader reader)
        : base(reader)
    { }

    protected override char Normalize(char c)
    {
        return char.ToLower(c, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    protected override bool IsTokenChar(char c)
    {
        // TAB has the same code in Unicode
        return c != '\x0009';
    }
}
```

Comment: What takes longer, exactly?  Just the analysis?  Or does this also include parsing a query, searching the index, or adding a document?  Also, how much of a time increase are you seeing?

Comment: I see that the indexing, specifically adding a Document takes twice as long. I create a document in each iteration, and reusing the Field objects.

Comment: Okay, my guess is that any performance impact from the analysis itself is trivial, and the hit you are seeing has more to do with what the document looks like after analysis, how it's being indexed, or possibly even how your performance test is implemented.  Profiling it might help find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to update this thread : the issue was in the custom analyzer. I did not actually save the tokenizer to PreviousTokenStream , so it was creating a new tokenizer each time.